Visual Studio 2022 can't connect to a project due to bad filters
after formating my PC and setting it into a domain I have an issue connecting to Team Explorer, on the account filet I see wrong filters.
this is what I should see:
enter image description here
This is what I see:
enter image description here
I have tried clear cache, logout, and log in again and again. without any success.
our source control is on Azure Devops
here is another image:
enter image description here

Hi there, From the screenshots that you shared, you were unable to see the expected tenant/domain after signing-in VS, which could have you fail to authenticate your access to Azure Repos with the correct AAD identity. Have you tried to visit Azure Portal in InPrivate windows of your browser for a test, and can you switch to other tenants? When signing-in Azure Portal, does it prompt for your to select personal/work account?

Hi, all goof from the portal, if I connect to the DevOps repo using a link all good and I can sync, the only part that is not working is the connect to project. if I clicking the account setting in the VS account I can see the correct tenet and repos

You mean you can see the correct tenants in the VS account settings? But may I know why you shared the screenshots where the tenants were different with wrong filters?

Did you mean the tenant filter was related to how the issue was reproduced?

I dont see the tenant on the account setting on VS, only the login details and filters. how can I see the tenant

I am seeking to know your issue reproducing steps to see why your expected tenant was missing. As I mentioned, if your user account was not logged in as the identity in the tenant that your Azure DevOps organization was connected to, you were unable to connect to the projects in that organization via Team explorer.

By setting PC into a domain, can you specify what was your operation? Was it set into the AAD that your organization was connected to?

yes, the PC was entered into local Domain control and synced to 365 tenants, the filter I see on the PC with the issue is the domain my PC is attached to.  the weird issue is that connect to any repro directly working fine - means that the user is allow to handle those repo.

I added another image, the account is a stand-alone Microsoft account on the devops

I can still see the Azure DevOps organization that is not connected to any AAD in the Connect to a Project dropdown menu. Is it possible for you or any other user in this MS account organization to test on another machine that is not enrolled in local DC? We can use the AAD email account (user principal) to sign-in VS directly without using local domain account with AAD synchronization.

Other machine works fine on the same account, other users on the same domain works fine

Thanks for the sharing and it seemed that we could rule out the cause by the settings from Azure DevOps or AAD. The issue was more likely to be related to the VS settings on this specific machine. Can you have a test with the VS Account settings -> Account options -> Accounts -> Add and reauthenticate accounts using web browser and check Authenticate across all tenants when adding accounts?

Just test and using system web all OK, thanks for the supports and Idea

Thanks a lot for taking time to share the update. So glad to know the issue was resolved.

I have summarized some further findings based on our discussions, which may help other community members who encounter similar issues to narrow down the root cause. Thank you again for the sharing and efforts in this post. Cheers!

Based on the findings in further discussions,

The Azure DevOps organization was not connected to any AAD;

The Windows machine had joined an on-premises domain synchronized with AAD;

The user account was able to visit account-originating tenant in Azure Portal and was also able to access the Microsoft Account Azure DevOps organization in the browser of this machine;


The issue could be resolved by the change in Visual Studio Account Settings -> Account options -> Environment - Accounts -> Add and reauthenticate accounts using: System web browser.


RESOLVED, I moved the authentication from the default browser or Windows authentication broker to the system web browser and all logged-in currently and I see the correct filter under tenants.
enter image description here
